# External SD Card Detected, Files Not Showing

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, sd-card, storage, app2sd

Being a BLU fan, I have a BLU Neo 4.5. A few days ago, I had this really strange experience; I have my 64 GB external SD card inserted and my phone's storage setting detected it. 64GB. However, when I went to my file browser, it said that no contents were available and when I tried to move an app to the SD card, it said "Could not move app." I rebooted the phone and perfect. I could do it. However, later, the apps no longer worked. Does anyone know any possible reason as to why this is happening? I'm running Android 4.2.2

**What I've Tried, My Guess & More Info**

My guess is that I also used this same exact SD card on another phone, moving the same exact apps to it. Maybe formatting the SD will help? I already formatted my phone (factory reset) and so far, the file browser has not yet said that the SD card was empty.

What do you think I should do next? Format the SD Card to be safe, or carry on as it seems to be okay after the device's factory reset? Usually, is something like this more hardware or software-related? From what I know, it's usually software-related.

Also, on a side-note, it says that the phone only supports a 32GB SD, but I have a 64GB inserted and it works just fine, seemingly. Could that also be it?

**Update:** It stopped displaying the files again, even though it says the external card is mounted in Settings. I tried a new 32GB (supposedly "compatible") SD card so hopefully that'll work. If not, what do you presume is the case?x

Comment: Have you tried using a 32 Gig or lesser sized SD card in your phone? If so, did you experience any of the inconsistencies?

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> Also, on a side-note, it says that the phone only supports a 32GB SD,
>   but I have a 64GB inserted and it works just fine, *seemingly*. Could
>   that also be it?

Yeah, **seemingly**. Did you expect anything different?

Could that also be it? **YES**, with surety above 90% for me.

You appear trying to kinda 'cheat' your manufacturer, by using a size your phone doesn't support on paper. Perhaps, that's affecting the consistency of displaying the contents on your phone. For some phones, like Sony Xperia Z2, the storage won't show up at all if it goes beyond the recommended size limit on paper.

Instead of trying to go beyond whats recommended on paper, kindly stick to 32 Gig storage or less, as your manufacturer says. If it doesn't work, then there's a problem. Until that, you're just messing up with phone.

If sticking to 32 or less storage capacities, the inconsistencies exists, then you might consider:

- Trying your SD card in another phone to see if it works. If it works...
- Try a different file explorer on your phone.
- As a fallback, it might be an OS issue, and perhaps fixed in an update. Update your phone software.